# How to install OpenCV on Linux as regular user

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I am trying to install opencv on a remote server.
They said I am allowed to do it but I should do it
as a regular user and I won't have high level access
which means 'no sudo'!
So I want to know if there is a way to install it
only on my own account as a regular user.

I'm really new to Linux (I use ubuntu 11.10 ) and I used this guide for my
own PC:
[Installing OpenCV 2.2 in Ubuntu 11.04](http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/)

Thank you

Comment: never listened about OpenCV before, but reading the installation manual, and you have the source files, you sure can compile it without being root.

Comment: "sudo" will be needed if some prerequisite libraries are not installed on the machine(It likely happens). Better get a super user account or privilege.

Comment: Thank you I have OpenCV installed on my own systems ( windows7 and ubuntu 11.10) and the server uses linux. Is there a way to use the libraries I have installed on my own system?

Comment: you could download the .deb files and extract them to your own directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you would need to compile it yourself, it is explained here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

You simply download the tar.gz, then you extract it and goto that directory in a terminal.

When you've done this, you need to comfigure what you want and don't want first. You can do so by running either cmake or cmake-gui. Use cmake-gui, if you want a gui ;)

```
cmake-gui
```

in cmake-gui you needed to specify a directory where to put some files, go there in a terminal and run make.

```
make
```

After this you should search for a directory with your header-files (.h or .hpp) and one with your library-files (.a, .so and .o). Add the first to your INCLUDE_PATH directory and the second to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable ;)

That should do it. Please note that this is an 'in memory' explenation, as compiling opencv takes a long time, I did not try this myself. But feel free to comment if you still have questions. The best advice I would like to give you is use cmake-gui and see what options are available there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just a few more data points for you.

I was unable to get OpenCV 2.4.0 to build on my Debian 6 box (ubuntu 11 is based on Debian 6). OpenCV 2.3.1 compiled and installed fine but I had no end of problems with version 2.4.0.

But be aware that there are a number of package dependencies in order to build OpenCV. To install any of those dependencies WILL require sudo or root privileges.

I strongly second Herbert's suggestion to use cmake-gui, not the command line version of cmake. The gui version, cmake-gui, makes it so much easier to get all of the options right before you actually do the compilation.

Answer (score -3):

Here is what I followed from http://namhuy.net/1205/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu.html to install OpenCV on Ubuntu

```
$ su -
# apt-get update
# apt-get install build-essential
# apt-get install libavformat-dev
# apt-get install x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg
# apt-get install libcv2.3 libcvaux2.3 libhighgui2.3 python-opencv opencv-doc libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev
```